# Create json object with loop ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create a JSON object out of ruby object on view file like

```
:coffeescript
 files = {}
  - @filelist.each do |f|
    = files[f[0]] = f[1]
  console.log(files)
```

it gives me an "Unexpected logic" error

following is array declared in controller

```
@filelist = Array.new
@filelist.push(['ref','count'])
@filelist.push(['input1','count'])
@filelist.push(['input2','count'])
```

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place. The first step is to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In your view you first have to convert ruby array to json (inside view):

```
var filelists = $.parseJSON(<%= @filelist.to_json %>);
```

Then create a json object in view:

```
 var jsonObj = {};
    $.each(filelists, function(obj,index){
      jsonObj[obj[0]] = obj[1];
    });
```

Comment: it seems to be working except I want it in haml file. tried following but its not working - #{@filelist.to_json}

Comment: I have not worked using HAML files, but after looking at some tutorials I guess in HAML you would have to use this: `=@filelist.to_json`.